# 2 Condtions Do While - Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make my Macro run through files based on two conditions, code as follows:

```
Sub RefreshYesterday()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    FullName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    slice = Len(FullName) - Len(Name)
    FileDate = Left((FileDateTime(FullName)), 10)
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    folderPath = (Left(FullName, slice))

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsb")
    **Do While filename <> "" And FileDate <> Date**
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)

        'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
        Call Mymacro
        DoEvents


        filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  MsgBox "Update Complete " + GetXLUserName
End Sub
```

However the do while condition which is supposed to ignore files with a last updated date of today doesn't work, it works through every folder regardless of the date, any advice?

**Do While filename <> "" And FileDate <> Date**

Comment: What are the values of the variables while debugging? Did you already try using brackets : `(filename <> "") AND (FileDate <> Date)`?

Comment: Hi @Dominique,

I found in debugger filedate was a string but date was a date, I have declared the variable of "Filedate" to be a date but now instead of doing every file regardless of date it does none of them and skips to the end message???

Comment: There undeclared variables which can cause unexpected errors.  Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module then do Alt > d > l to compile the project.  Fix the compile errors and you won't need us.

Comment: What is the value of `Date`. Please add more details so we van help you.